# Passing lambda function from java class to kotlin class gives me error

Tags: java, android, kotlin, lambda

My kotlin class:

```
class InstallationReceiver(activity : RootActivity, url : String, progressCallback : 
((percentage : Int) -> Unit)?,  callback : ((isUpdated : Boolean) -> Unit)?, packageName: 
String){

//my code

}
```

I am passing lambda fun to this class from java class like this:

```
new InstallationReceiver(getActivity(), apkUrl, integer -> **{ 
String text = "Installing app"+integer;
textView.setText(text);
}**,true,null);
```

Why this lambda function is demanding a Unit return type?. I even tried returning Unit.INSTANCE
but nothing helped me out. It's still showing error.

Comment: Mostly because `((percentage : Int) -> Unit)?` means passing an `Integer` and getting back a `Unit` of data.

Comment: yeah, I figured it out. Problem is in the other lambda function while I was thinking it is in 1st one. Thanks BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are those asterisks?
I tried this minimal example and it works:

Kotlin

```
class InstallationReceiver(
    a: ((percentage: Int) -> Unit)?
)
```

Java

```
new InstallationReceiver(percentage -> {
    String text = "Installing app" + percentage;
    return Unit.INSTANCE;
});
```

Also, you're passing `true` and `null` where the constructor expects a lambda (`(isUpdated : Boolean) -> Unit`) and a non-nullable `String`.
You can get away with compiling while passing a null string (you shouldn't since the app will crash at runtime), but for sure you need to pass a lambda instead of a boolean.
Something similar to the example above:

```
isUpdated -> {
    // your code
    return Unit.INSTANCE;
}
```

Comment: I put those asterisks to my code where I thought the error is.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I used the return statement Unit.INSTANCE and now its working fine.